# does javascript remove event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

On a test webpage I have, there is a link like so:

```
<a href="default.html?tab=1" id="t1" onclick="switchf('home',this)">HOME</a>
```

The style for it is like so:

```
nav > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0000aa;
    display: inline-block;
        width: 80px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
nav > a:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

and `switchf()` (switch field) is like so:

```
function switchf(field,tab) {       
    document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("account").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("contact").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("t1").style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
    document.getElementById("t2").style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
    document.getElementById("t3").style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
        document.getElementById("t4").style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";

    document.getElementById(field).style.display = "inline-block";
    tab.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
}
```

The link basically acts as a tab, to show a different thing. There are three others like it.

The JavaScript works fine switching tabs, but when I hover over a tab after I've used `switchf()`, it doesn't change color anymore.

Is there something wrong with my code?

thanks.

**EDIT**

this is how I fixed mine:

first, I added `class="tab"` to all the links, so they looked like this:

```
<a href="?tab=1" id="t1" class="tab" onclick="switchf('home',this)">HOME</a><br />
```

second, I changed the javascript so that the function `switchf()` was like this:

```
function switchf(field,tab) {       
    document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("account").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("contact").style.display = "none";

    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");  // here is different
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
        t[i].addEventListener("mouseover");
        t[i].addEventListener("mouseout");
    }

    document.getElementById(field).style.display = "inline-block";
    tab.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with an event listener?  You have no listener for mouse events here, right?  Just "click".

Comment: i meant `hover`, in the css

Comment: @Jon There is no need to edit your question to add "thank you, it's solved". Marking an answer as "accepted" is enough. Good luck with getting better in the latest web technologies!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inline CSS takes precedence over stylesheets. Once you click on a link, it will set the `background-color` property for all links, hence all links will not change color when you hover over it.

A better alternative than hard-coding the style in your elements, you can try adding a CSS class to your links (like `page-active`) and style those elements as needed.

Yet another alternative that saves you from clearing old classes is adding a class or ID to the page and use that to hide/show links as needed.

```
<style>
nav > a {
    display: none;
}
#page-about nav > a#link-home {
    display: inline-block;
}
<body id="page-about">
    <nav>
        <a href="?tab=home" id="link-home">Home</a>
        <a href="?tab=about" id="link-about">About</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

This should give you a general idea, polishing it is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: To add to this answer, you would be better off creating a class that gets added to the element when it gets clicked so that you can manage the styles in the stylesheet itself instead of in the javascript.

Comment: but shouldn't that only set the `background-color` property for when it's not being hovered over? why should it change the `background-color` property for when it's being hovered over?

Comment: so do you know if there a way to set the `background-color` property only for the `a`, not `a:hover`?

Comment: @Jon **Inline CSS takes precedence over stylesheets** regardless of a selector like `:hover`. Use CSS classes to mark specific links as "active" and use Javascript *only* to add/remove that class from links.

Comment: if you look at the edited question, I added `addEventListener("mouseover")` and `addEventListener("mouseout")` and it worked. not exactly sure what that means, though

Comment: @Jon Assume the `"tag"` string to be a typo, that is *not* the way to go. It probably "works" because your scripts errors out when it encounters too few arguments for `addEventListener`. See the [MDN documentation on addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener). Try to solve this problem without using `style.backgroundColor = "..."`, use CSS instead with classes (e.g. [using `classlist`](http://caniuse.com/classlist)).